# How to pad strings in a vector under paste0() sequentially

Tags: r

I can do the following:

```
> paste0("cat.", 1:10, ".jpg")
```

which gives:

```
[1] "cat.1.jpg"  "cat.2.jpg"  "cat.3.jpg"  "cat.4.jpg"  "cat.5.jpg"  "cat.6.jpg"  "cat.7.jpg"  "cat.8.jpg" 
[9] "cat.9.jpg"  "cat.10.jpg"
```

How can I pad the `paste0()` to produce

```
[1] "cat.01.jpg"  "cat.02.jpg"  "cat.03.jpg"  "cat.04.jpg"  "cat.05.jpg"  "cat.06.jpg"  "cat.07.jpg"  "cat.08.jpg" 
[9] "cat.09.jpg"  "cat.10.jpg"
```

At the end of the day what I want to do is to have sequence until 1000

```
paste0("cat.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
```

To get string like `cat.0001.jpg`.

Comment: Try `sprintf("cat.%04d.jpg", 1:1000)`.

Comment: @nicola Why post this as a comment, if this is the answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use `stringr's` `str_pad` as below:

```
library(stringr)
paste0("cat.", str_pad(1:10,width=2,side="left", pad=0), ".jpg")
```

To make it scalable to 1000, you can choose to change the second parameter (width) of str_pad to 4.

```
?str_pad
```

> Vectorised over string, width and pad.
>
> Usage
>
> str_pad(string, width, side = c("left", "right", "both"), pad = " ")

**Output**:

```
> paste0("cat.", str_pad(1:10,2,pad=0), ".jpg")
 [1] "cat.01.jpg" "cat.02.jpg" "cat.03.jpg"
 [4] "cat.04.jpg" "cat.05.jpg" "cat.06.jpg"
 [7] "cat.07.jpg" "cat.08.jpg" "cat.09.jpg"
[10] "cat.10.jpg"
```

you may also choose to use `stringr::str_c` instead of `paste0`

Answer (score 0):

No need for additional dependencies. You can just use `sprintf()` from base R as below:

```
sprintf("cat.%04d.jpg", 1:1000)
```